# Rails use Model method in a group query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am using [has_ancentry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem and I want to have the category count is this format

"Technology / Laptop (50)"

where "Technology" is parent category. "Laptop" is child category, and "50" is the count of my grouped query

```
categories = Category.joins(:products)
                         .where(products: {id: @products})
                         .group(:id, :name)
                         .count
```

The problem is that in this way I get only the "ID" of child category. If I would to retrieve the "parent" category I have to have the active record object (because in has_ancestry .parent() is a method object and not a database column)

**Model**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
```

**Categories**

```
 create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
        t.string "ancestry"
        t.index ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry"
      end
```

Comment: please update your post that includes model and association. we needs more information to solve the problem,

Comment: done. I've added Category model.

Comment: please add the actual schema rather than just the model because at the end of the day you should have some kind of id to get the child products

Comment: done. it's a classic has_ancestry table

Answer (score 0):

I have some kind of confusing to understand a problem.

But I have some solutions.

ancestry gem does not support the query interface for the association

So I use

dirty way: it causes n+1 query problem

```
Category.joins(:products).where(products: {id: @products}).group(:id, :name).count
        .map { |k, v| "#{Category.find(k.first).parent.name} / #{k.last} (#{v})" }
```

short way: it causes n+1 query problem

```
Product.group(:category).size.map { |k, v| "#{k.parent.name} / #{k.name} (#{v})" }
```

short way2: it causes n+1 query problem

```
Category.includes(:products).map { |c| [c.parent&.name, c.name, c.products.size]}
```

I want to use raw query but I currently could not thinking a good sql, sorry,

update new one:

```
products = Product.group(:category).size
categories = Category.where(id: products.map(&:first).map(&:ancestry).uniq).pluck(:id, :name)
result = products.map { |child_category, total| "#{(categories.select { |c| c.first == child_category.ancestry.to_i }.map(&:last)).first} / #{child_category.name} (#{total})" }
```

This looks some complicate, but has just two query.

It needs more computing power in your machine.

Comment: Yes, I can sold the problem causing a N+1 query. I would do it without causing a n+1 query